# create a global component with children using multiple props in vue and nuxt js

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

I am trying to build global a component with children and multiple props for multiple usage. i don't know where i am making a mistake. here is my component file

> SectionHeading.vue

```
<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import Heading from '~/components/Heading.vue'

  Vue.component('SectionHeading', {
    props: {
      heading: [String],
      content: [String]
    },
    template: '<div><Heading>{{ heading }}</Heading><p>{{ content }}</p></div>'
    // this may be not necessary
  })

  export default {
    components: {
      Heading
    }
  }
</script>

<template>
  <b-container class="text-center">
      <span><img src="~/assets/images/Icon.svg" alt="" /></span>
      <Heading :level="3">{{ heading }}</Heading>
      <p>{{ content }}</p>
  </b-container>
</template>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped lang="scss">

</style>
```

Here is my `index` file where i am importing `SectionHeading` component

> index.vue

```
<template>
  <section class="">
    <SectionHeading heading="About Me" content="lorem ipsum" />
  </section>
</template>

<script>
  import SectionHeading from '~/components/SectionHeading.vue'
  export default {
    components: {
      SectionHeading
    },
    data () {
      return {
        title: 'Home'
      }
    },
    head () {
      return {
        title: this.title
      }
    }
  }
</script>
<style>

</style>
```

**i want it to be render as below**

```
<div class="contaniner">
  <span><img src="images/Icon.svg" alt="" /></span>
  <h3>About Me</h3>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

**what i am getting is**

```
<div class="container">
 <span><img src="images/Icon.svg" alt="" /></span>
 <h3></h3>
 <p></p> 
</div>
```

the error i am getting [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're going about this and trying to create a global component the "Vue way" when you really should do it the "Nuxt way".

The "Nuxt way" would go something like this:

```
//components/SectionHeading.vue
<script>
import Heading from '~/components/Heading.vue'

export default {
  props: ['heading', 'content'],
  components: {
    Heading
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <b-container class="text-center">
      <span><img src="~/assets/images/Icon.svg" alt="" /></span>
      <Heading :level="3">{{ heading }}</Heading>
      <p>{{ content }}</p>
  </b-container>
</template>

<style scoped lang="scss">

</style>
```

Then you want to create a file in the plugins directory, lets call it global.js

```
//plugins/global.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import SectionHeading from '~/components/SectionHeading.vue'

Vue.component('section-heading', SectionHeading)
```

And then register that plugin in nuxt.config.js

```
//nuxt.config.js
...
plugins: [ '@/plugins/global.js' ]
...
```

and you should be right to use it in any page as

`<section-heading heading="blah" content="blah more"/>`

Comment: working fine. thanks for the solution. what if i want to add `<br>` in `p` tag? see if you can help me out :)

Comment: In your SectionHeading.vue? Do you mean like: `<p>{{ content }}<br> Some other content</p>`? You can add as many <br> as you like.

Comment: No, i mean `br` inside `content` for multiple lines

Comment: That is up to how you structure your content. You could include html in your content like: `<p>This is <br> our content</p>` and then render it with v-html. Replace `<p>{{ content }}</p>` with `<p v-html="content"></p>` although maybe more likely a div or something, <div v-html="content"></div>. Otherwise you'd have to have to use javascript, things like split(), replace(), or join() to alter the "content" string either to break into several strings or to insert line breaks.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Answer accepted. :)